# WPF Bind field of class instance to data trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I have PivotGridControl with next fields

```
<dxpg:PivotGridControl.Fields>
    <dxpg:PivotGridField FieldName="CourierFullName" 
                         Area="RowArea"
                         Caption="Courier"/>
    <dxpg:PivotGridField FieldName="Header" 
                         Area="ColumnArea"
                         Caption="Data" 
                         ValueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" SortOrder=
                         "Descending"/>
    <dxpg:PivotGridField Area="DataArea" 
                         SummaryType="Min"
                         CellTemplate="{StaticResource CellTemplate}"/>
</dxpg:PivotGridControl.Fields>
```

Information for fill provided by class

```
public class CourierFlattenRow
{
    public DateTime Header { get; set; }
    public string CourierFullName { get; set; }
    public TariffZone TariffZone { get; set; }
    public DeliveryTerm DeliveryTerm { get; set; } 
    public CourierExtraEvent ExtraEvent { get; set; }
}
```

How I can set data trigger for painting cell, if field ExtraEvent.IsWorkingDay == true ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want an item to be displayed if ExtraEvent.IsWorkingDay is True and not displayed otherwise.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ExtraEvent.IsWorkingDay}" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunatly, its working for GridControl, but not PivotGrid